# On Touch Listener is overlapping with relativie layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, imagebutton, ontouchlistener

I have two `ImageButton` and I want to set the same `OnTouchListener`  for both of them, but the issue is overlapping, when I touch one Image another adjacent Image is also moving.
When I touch Image 2, it is moving out of screen and getting invisible. I want it to remain on Screen and Touch event should work separately for them.

here is what I did till now.

```java
    //this is the snippet from main activity where the onTouch is implemented and layout is created       

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imgMaster.setLayoutParams(params);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imgMaster.getId());
    imgMaster.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    imgMood.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    imgMood.setLayoutParams(params);
    imgMaster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Master", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    imgMood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Mood", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        //ImageButton views = (ImageButton) view;
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.master: 
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDelta = X - lparams.leftMargin;
                        _yDelta = Y - lparams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
            case R.id.mood:
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDelta = X - lparams.leftMargin;
                        _yDelta = Y - lparams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

       
        return false;

    }

}
```

//Here is My Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/view_root"
android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mood"
    android:src="@drawable/mood"

    android:background="@null"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/master"
    android:src="@drawable/master"
    android:background="@null" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these images overlapping on each other to begin with ? I am asking this because you have used a relative layout and not mentioned the relative position of each image with respect to each other

Comment: @Dibzmania but add rule is already define for position in code

Comment: @Dibzmania May be its overlapping...but If I am setting similar to in layout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" for image its not making any change....

Comment: May be problem is only in add rule

Comment: Because When i am adding position in add rule() as left , right then its adjacent problem is occuring

Comment: But if I will do it for three image as params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE); then its moving fine but image is overlapping so how to solve it?

Comment: I have checked and added the answer ,please upvote and mark it as answer , if you think it deserves the same. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As you asked for the code** , here it is, but still I don't know what actual movement you want from your object to do .

**The code I m providing would let you drag the two objects wherever you want on the screen without moving the other object along with.**

Hope this is something you wanted (might be closer at least)

**NOTE :** please remove all `RelativeLayout.addRule()` etc , just set onTouch listener to your **ImageButtons** ,Below is the definition of Ontouch

```
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.master:
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.setX(X-view.getWidth()/2);
                            view.setY(Y-view.getHeight());
                            break;
                    }
                case R.id.mood:
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.setX(X-view.getWidth()/2);
                            view.setY(Y-view.getHeight());
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
                return false;

        }
```

This should be your layout in XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_root"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/master"
        android:src="@drawable/master"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mood"
        android:src="@drawable/mood"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/master"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/master" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Working Perfect

Comment: You can upvote my answer as well ,if you think I really put some effort into it , thanks:)